# SSRS Report Column Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to recreate a report to look similar to an old report and am having issues. What I'm trying to do is

[image: Image 1].

But what I keep getting is this:

[image: Image 2]

While the report itself is working correctly in 2 I want to be able to expand the Type Column to get rid of the blue space.

Answer (score 0):

To expand Type column, select contract row group properties , select visiibilty, select Show when report is initially run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drill-down report by following this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-ssrs-drill-down-report/

or this:

https://www.dynamics101.com/how-to-make-a-drill-down-report-in-ssrs/

Comment: Thanks Somad. I'll check it out.

Comment: Link only answers are not good answers as they are invalidated if the links fail. Please add the relevant information directly to your answer.